# Appreciate help in identifying this vintage IC - Fairchild HL41109 QB

Tags: integrated-circuit, ceramic, vintage, gold

Trying to find out what this one is has been a real head-scratcher. Google leads me down numerous rabbit-holes to dead ends. And I see 1 or 2 for sale on eBay, but apparently they have no idea what it is either. Insight, help, moral support would all be greatly appreciated - thanks! [image: Fairchild HL41109QB]

Comment: What are the devices used in? Where did you get them or see them?

Comment: This question is the top google hit for HL41109 so clearly it is not a commonly known part.  There is no reason it can't be a custom or customer configured part.  If you are trying to replace them @Andy aka has the right suggestions, if you are trying to price or market them good luck.

Comment: The IC's in OP's photo have especific codes written in: "176-148" (for that one fabricated in 7532), "176-090A" (fabricated 7631), and the one selling in ebay has "176-221" (fabricated 7719). I would preffer to be out of this hand; if I really had to bet, I would bet that this is a mask ROM.

Comment: If this is a custom marked version of a part with a public datasheet, you might find it in https://bitsavers.org/components/harris/ perhaps in the 1975 databook. Unfortunately they don't seem to have die photos. If this was a fully custom ASIC with no public datasheet, there is no way to identify it.

Comment: @Andy - As to where I got them, that’s a really good question...  My company has been buying and selling scientific, medical and industrial surplus for over 20 years.  I squirreled these away sometime ago and am thinking its government lab related surplus or maybe really old Hewlett Packard material.

Comment: @crassic I am trying to price them for inclusion on our electronics parts website.  I am slowly cataloging a mountain of stuff and uncovered these recently.  Thanks for the ‘good luck’ it’s much needed and appreciated!

Comment: @MarkU - Thanks for the link to bitsavers, will definitely check it out!

Comment: @mguima - Thanks, I’m going to start learning and getting more familar with ROMs from that era. Lords knows that I’m certain run across more of this type of stuff.